# ReferenceError: $ is not defined although jQuery is properly initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am only starting with JS, jQuery and Node JS and now trying to run my Simon Game from Hyper on a localhost:3000 server. I am getting a reference error on the first $ sign in my JS code like this:

> \Simon_Game\game2.js:18
>
> $(document).keypress(function() { ^   ReferenceError: $ is not defined
> at Object. (C:\Users\dkhme\OneDrive\The Complete 2020 Web
> Development Bootcamp\Web Development\Simon_Game\game2.js:18:3)    at
> Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)  at
> Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)  at
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)     at
> Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain]
> (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)  at
> internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting
> for file changes before starting...

I have properly referenced jQuery in my HTML before linking to my external JS code. Below are my HTML and JS codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="level-title">Press Any Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="bbtn green">

      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="bbtn red">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="bbtn yellow">

      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="bbtn blue">

      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="rules btn btn-light btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
      Rules / Правила
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Rules of the Game / Правила игры</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>ENG</p>
            <p>On your screen there are four colored buttons, each producing a particular tone when pressed or activated by the game. A round in the game consists of the game lighting up one random button, after which you must reproduce a sequence of
              buttons by pressing on them. On each level the game flashes only one button - the last in the current sequence. You must start by correctly reproducing the entire sequence of the previous level plus the button flashed by the game at the
              start of the current level. The level number corresponds to the total number of buttons in the current sequence. With each new level, the number of buttons to be pressed increases by one.</p>
            <p>RUS</p>
            <p>Игра представляет собой экран с четырьмя большими разноцветными кнопками, издающими разные звуки. Задача игры — запомнить продемонстрированную игроку последовательность этих вспышек и звуков и впоследствии воспроизвести её в рамках
              «раунда» игры. Начать игру можно нажатием любой кнопки. В каждом раунде игра показывает одну кнопку, которая должна стать последней в текущем раунде. Сначала необходимо воспроизвести последовательность кнопок предыдущего раунда и
              закончить его кнопкой, показанной в начале текущего раунда. Номер раунда соответствует общему количеству кнопок в текущей последовательности. С каждым раундом количество кнопок увеличивается на одну.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

  <script src="game2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>

<footer>
  <h5>Created by Dennis Norrstrand. Helsinki, Finland 2020.</h5>
</footer>

</html>
```

game2.js:

```
const express = require("express");
  const https = require("https");
  const app = express();
  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

  app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
  })

  let buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];

  let gamePattern = [];
  let userClickedPattern = [];

  let started = false;
  let level = 0;

  $(document).keypress(function() {
    if (!started) {
      $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
      nextSequence();
      started = true;
    }
  });

  $(".bbtn").click(function() {

    let userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");
    userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);

    playSound(userChosenColour);
    animatePress(userChosenColour);

    checkAnswer(userClickedPattern.length - 1);
  });

  function checkAnswer(currentLevel) {

    if (gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {
      if (userClickedPattern.length === gamePattern.length) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          nextSequence();
        }, 1000);
      }
    } else {
      playSound("wrong");
      $("body").addClass("game-over");
      $("#level-title").text("Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart");

      setTimeout(function() {
        $("body").removeClass("game-over");
      }, 200);

      startOver();
    }
  }

  function nextSequence() {
    userClickedPattern = [];
    level++;
    $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    let randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
    gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);

    $("#" + randomChosenColour).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    playSound(randomChosenColour);
  }

  function animatePress(currentColor) {
    $("#" + currentColor).addClass("pressed");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#" + currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
    }, 100);
  }

  function playSound(name) {
    let audio = new Audio("sounds/" + name + ".mp3");
    audio.play();
  }

  function startOver() {
    level = 0;
    gamePattern = [];
    started = false;
  }

  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000.");
  });
```

Why am I getting this reference error? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Require is Node.js and you can't load jQuery there

Comment: You are very much confusing server side code with client side code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jquery is not loaded properly. Remove the comments and add this above the line you are using `<script src="game2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```